# "if" and "or" condition in the RTF template not working

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I am trying to use or condition in the rtf template but its not working and not taking all the conditions.

```
<?if:REPORTING_NAME!='Vacation' or REPORTING_NAME!='Sick' or REPORTING_NAME!='LOA'?>
```

This is not working and i am still getting the REPORTING_NAME='COVID Sick Retro' in my  column.

How to use the or and if clause together in RTF correctly?

Comment: Can you give some Example XML and what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Pls use the below in the rtf template

```
<?if:(CUSTOMER_NAME='DOG') or (CUSTOMER_NAME='CAT')?>
```